# JS. Как получить дочерние элементы для блока с id внутри svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Есть блок object через который вызывается svg файл

`<object id="floor1_plan" type="image/svg+xml" data="map/map1.svg" height="100%" width="100%"></object>`

Далее из этого блока я получаю данные:

```
var floor = document.getElementById("floor1_plan").contentDocument;
```

Внутри этой SVG есть блок с id="floor" в котором так же есть элементы со своими id, пытался вытащить id этих элементов через

```
var rooms = $('#floor').toArray().map(el => el.id);
```

но в данном случае нет привязки к svg.

Как привязаться к этому svg и работать непосредственно внутри него?

Comment: вставить его непосредственно в в страницу, а не через object ?

Comment: Он динамически подгружаемый

Comment: динамически подгрузите `$("#wrapper").load("/map/map1.svg");`

Comment: Не думаю что хорошая идея изменить тип подгрузки уже в проекте

Comment: А вы писали типа виндоу.онлоад  ?

Comment: И в js вы получаете другой объект , не тот что в html

Comment: А где вы вообще обращаетесь к svg? Вы вытащили его в переменную, а потом пишите $(...) который ищет в текущем документе

Comment: @AlexeyTen он даже не то получил, в html у него `floor1_plan` а в js у него совсем другое `floor1__plan`

Comment: @maximlensky, опечатка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(floor).find("#floor > *")
```